# PHP Decrease Code Character Count

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach, rss

I have a snippet of code that reads an RSS feed and displays the first 5 results.

It all works as expected, however in order to suits my needs the total amount of characters need to be **no more than** 350. Currently it's at 370.

Is there any way to "minify" this code so that the functionality remains the same, but it's no more than 350 characters.

**Code**;

```
<?php
$r = simplexml_load_file("https://example.com/feed");
if(!empty($r)) {
    $i=0;
    foreach ($r->channel->item as $f) {
        if($i>=5) break;
        ?>
        <p><a href="<?= $f->link; ?>"><?= $f->title; ?></a></p>
        <p><?= implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $f->description), 0, 14)) . "..."; ?></p>
        <?php       
        $i++;   
    }
}
?>
```

**Notes**;

- I need to echo the title as a html link
- I need the title and description to be on individual paragraphs
- I need to truncate the description

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: That's a silly requirement. Start by removing unneeded white space, changing variable names to single characters, `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`. Then go stab whoever gave you the task with a rusty butter knife.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: It does sound like homework @IncredibleHat but interestingly enough it's not :/

Comment: I was able to reduce it to about 259 chars... a big waster is all the open/close php you do. Put all of that into a single echo and you save many chars. And get rid of all spaces and tabs within reason ;) `echo "<p><a href='{$f->link}'>{$f->title}</a></p><p>".implode(' ',array_slice(explode(' ',$f->description),0,14)).'...</p>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was something I reduced to 251-255 chars (remove newlines to reduce a few more):

```
<?php
if($r = simplexml_load_file("https://example.com/feed")){
$i=0;foreach($r->channel->item as $f){if($i>=5){break;}$i++;
echo "<p><a href='{$f->link}'>{$f->title}</a></p><p>".implode(' ',array_slice(explode(' ',$f->description),0,14))."...</p>";
}}
?>
```

By doing the 'falsey' compare in the if block while assigning, you can shave even more off. This should work, as if simplexml_load_file returns something, it should be the xml, false if it failed, which will make it not do the block.

There may be some more simplification for that odd implode/array_slice/explode, but I didn't find one in initial tests.

I would do `foreach($r->channel->item as $i=>$f){if($i>=5){break;}` instead, but I am unsure if your xml return will be of pure indexed array or not.